# Prefix all routes with string

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm trying to prefix all my routes with `api/health`. Here's the setup/code I have:

`routes/food.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const foodController = require('../controllers/food');

router.get('/', foodController.getAllFood)

module.exports = router
```

`routes/index.js`

```
const foodRoute = require('./food');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use('/food', foodRoute)
};
```

And in `/index.js` I call `require('./routes')(app);`.

How can I make all routes have a prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your `foodRoute` modular (ie without hard-coding in the base path), you can pass it a router instead of the root `app`

```js
// /index.js

const apiRouter = express.Router();
app.use("/api/health", apiRouter);

require("./routes")(apiRouter);
```